# If $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ and $g(n)$ is $O(f(n))$, is $f(n) = g(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

> *Question*: If $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ and $g(n)$ is $O(f(n))$, is $f(n) = g(n)$?

I'm studying for a discrete mathematics test, and I'm not sure if this is true or false.  Since Big-OH ignores constant multiples, wouldn't $f(n) = c\, g(n)$?

Comment: Why a close vote?  The author put in a bit of context and their own idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$f(n) = an^2$
and
$g(n) = bn^2$
where $a$ and $b$ are 
distinct positive reals.

Both
$f(n) = O(g(n))$
and
$g(n) = O(f(n))$
are true,
but $f(n) \ne g(n)$
for $n > 0$.

This is often written as
$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Answer (score 4):

Your thoughts are correct. Consider $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = 2f(n)$ as a counter example.

Comment: But to clarify, it needn't be the case that one function is a constant multiple of the other.

Comment: Yes, it was just one counter example :)